# Actionscript library on c++

Tags: c++, actionscript

I'm looking for Actionscript library, written on c++, that contain Actionscrimp classs , like video , camera , netconnection , netstream and so on...
Someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using openFrameworks:  http://www.openframeworks.cc/

Comment: thank you very much for helpful information! Is it possible to create chat application with this frameworks, that will able communicate with rtmp server, like flash application do?